# Redirect on JQuery between other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, redirect

How do I redirect to any page after the script below got sucess?
Something like: If the code below did everything right, I need to go to the thanks page. Please help me. Thanks

```js
jQuery(function(t) {
    var e = function() {
            var e = ("https:" == location.protocol ? "https:" : "http:") + "//formoid.net/api/push",
                a = function() {
                    var e = (/MSIE (\d+)\./.exec(navigator.userAgent) || [0, 0])[1]
                    return 8 == e || 9 == e && "file:" != location.protocol ? function(e, a) {
                        var n = new XDomainRequest,
                            r = t.Deferred()
                        return n.open(a.type, e), n.onload = function() {
                            r.resolve(this.responseText)
                        }, n.onerror = function() {
                            r.reject()
                        }, n.send(a.data), r
                    } : (t.support.cors = !0, t.ajax)
                }(),
                n = function(t, e) {
                    return t = "__" + t + "__", e.length ? (this[t] = e[0], this) : this[t]
                },
                r = function(e, a, n) {
                    return t.each(n, function(t, n) {
                        e[n] = function() {
                            return a[n].apply(a, arguments)
                        }
                    }), e
                },
                i = function(t) {
                    t = t || {}, this.__email__ = t.email || "", this.__title__ = t.title || "", this.__data__ = t.data || []
                }
            return i.prototype.email = function(t) {
                return n.call(this, "email", arguments)
            }, i.prototype.title = function(t) {
                return n.call(this, "title", arguments)
            }, i.prototype.data = function(t) {
                return n.call(this, "data", arguments)
            }, i.prototype.send = function(n, i) {
                var o = r(t.Deferred(), this, ["email", "title", "data", "send"])
                return i && (i.call(this, o), "pending" != o.state()) ? o : (a(e, {
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        email: this.__email__,
                        form: {
                            title: this.__title__,
                            data: arguments.length ? n : this.__data__
                        }
                    })
                }).done(function(t) {
                    try {
                        var e = JSON.parse(t)
                        e.error ? o.reject(e.error) : o.resolve(e.response)
                    } catch (a) {
                        o.reject("Incorrect server response.")
                    }
                }).fail(function() {
                    var t = "Failed to query the server. "
                    t += "onLine" in navigator && !navigator.onLine ? "No connection to the Internet." : "Check the connection and try again.", o.reject(t)
                }), o)
            }, {
                Form: function(t) {
                    return new i(t)
                }
            }
        }(),
        a = function(e) {
            if (e.checkValidity) return e.checkValidity()
            var a = !0,
                n = t(e).val(),
                r = t(e).attr("type")
            return n ? a = !("email" === r && !/^([^@]+?)@(([a-z0-9]-*)*[a-z0-9]+\.)+([a-z0-9]+)$/i.test(n)) : t(e).attr("required") && (a = !1), t(e)[(a ? "remove" : "add") + "Class"]("form-invalid"), a
        }
    t('[data-form-type="formoid"]').each(function() {
        var n, r = t(this),
            i = r.is("form") ? r : r.find("form"),
            o = r.find("[data-form-alert]"),
            s = r.is("[data-form-title]") ? r : r.find("[data-form-title]"),
            l = r.find('[type="submit"]'),
            c = o.attr("data-success") || o.find("[data-form-alert-success]").html()
        l.html('<span class="btn-text">' + l.html() + '</span><i class="btn-loader"></i>').click(function() {
            i.addClass("form-active")
        }), i.submit(function(d) {
            if (d.preventDefault(), i.addClass("form-active"), !l.hasClass("btn-loading")) {
                var f = !0,
                    u = []
                n = n || e.Form({
                    email: r.find("[data-form-email]").val(),
                    title: s.attr("data-form-title") || s.text()
                }), o.html(""), r.find("[data-form-field]").each(function() {
                    a(this) || (f = !1), u.push([t(this).attr("data-form-field") || t(this).attr("name"), t(this).val()])
                }), f && (l.addClass("btn-loading").prop("disabled", !0), n.send(u).done(function(e) {
                    i.removeClass("form-active"), r.find("[data-form-field]").val(""), o.append(t('<div class="alert alert-form alert-success text-xs-center"/>').text(c || e))
                }).fail(function(e) {
                    o.append(t('<div class="alert alert-form alert-danger text-xs-center"/>').text(e))
                }).always(function() {
                    l.removeClass("btn-loading").prop("disabled", !1)
                }))
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Everything works fine but in the end I want to redirect to a page right after the form data has been sent. Can you help me? Thanks

Comment: Can you post readable code or at least explain what the right and wrong conditions are?

Comment: Everything works fine but in the end I want to redirect to a page right after the form data has been sent.

Comment: that code is not even remotely readable still.

Answer (score 0):

Bind an event to the submit of the form, if you have one, or run a callback after a successful response comes back from the server and use `window.location` to send the user to your desired URL. More information on `window.location` can be found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location. (Look at the example #1)

I can't say more than that from the code you shared.

Comment: Hi Cherna, thanks for your attention.

I have a form. The example 3 is interesting. I feel its not about code issue but its about where to put the code string correctly. 

Inside the code I sent, do you know where must I put the code string in a correct way without break other functions already written?

Thanks